# Flask scripts or Machine Image for Python on AWS?

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scripting

I have a Meteor app deployed on AWS that uses Python scripts for a large amount of automation. What is the most effective way to handle these scripts with AWS?